# SQL people flow based on time and location

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a situation where I'm trying to get the flow of people through zones.

I have the data with timestamp and the location of the person when captured by the system.

The normal case is when a person location changes it should be added to the array "path", if date is more than an hour after previous entry then that row is finished and a new row should be started with that new path. Column "start" should be the first date used for that row and "end" should be the last.

Original data:

```
date,   macAddress,         zone
8h10m,  00-B0-D0-63-C2-26, room1
8h12m,  00-B0-D0-63-C2-26, hall
8h15m,  00-A0-B0-23-T2-22, room1
8h16m,  00-A0-B0-23-T2-22, meeting2
8h18m,  00-B0-D0-63-C2-26, meeting2
8h25m,  00-A0-B0-23-T2-22, cafetaria
8h30m,  00-G5-A8-44-T2-30, room1
8h34m,  00-G5-A8-44-T2-30, meeting2
8h49m,  00-G5-A8-44-T2-30, meeting2
14h05m, 00-G5-A8-44-T2-30, cafetaria
14h15m, 00-G5-A8-44-T2-30, room1
```

Result required in the following way (or similar):

```
macAddress,           start   end     path
00-B0-D0-63-C2-26,    8h10m,  8h18m,  [room1, hall, meeting2]
00-A0-B0-23-T2-22,    8h15m,  8h25m,  [room1, meeting2, cafetaria]
00-G5-A8-44-T2-30,    8h30m,  8h49m,  [room1, meeting2]
00-G5-A8-44-T2-30,    14h05m, 14h15m, [cafetaria, room1]
```

Can you give me an idea of how can I get such result in SQL? I'm using BigQuery, but I believe standard SQL should do the job.

Thanks,

Diogo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below query:

1. partition **time** of each person using window funtions first and then calculate the metrics of expected output.

```sql
SELECT macAddress,
       MIN(date) AS start, MAX(date) AS `end`,
       FORMAT('%t', ARRAY_AGG(IF(idle IS FALSE AND stay IS TRUE, NULL, zone) IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY date)) AS path
  FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNTIF(idle) OVER (PARTITION BY macAddress ORDER BY time) AS div
      FROM (
        SELECT *, 
               TIME_DIFF(time, LAG(time) OVER w, HOUR) >= 1 AS idle,
               zone = LAG(zone) OVER w AS stay
          FROM sample_table, UNNEST([PARSE_TIME('%Hh%Mm', date)]) time
        WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY macAddress ORDER BY time)
      )
  ) AS t
 GROUP BY macAddress, div;
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply i've been on vacation without access to my PC. It works really well, I just have one problem that i've been trying to fix but can't seem to make it work, when there's entries with the same zone one after the other it is supposed to be assumed that the person stayed in the zone so it wouldn’t be added to the array. For example, on row 4 the path is [room1, meeting2, meeting2] and it would be helpful if it was [room1, meeting2]

Comment: @DiogoMagalhães, I've updated the query to remove duplicated zone. Kindly check if it fits your requirements.